# Downloading csv file with tag "Download Error" while clicking on Download button from application in UI Automation with Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

While I execute automated testcase(Protractor Version 5.4.2) related to download functionality on my local machine, it is downloading .csv file with "Download error". I am sure it is not an issue with my application because when I manually perform exact steps I am able to download csv file without any error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your try your test with following settings in your config.js file

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
               '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection',
                '--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist'
              ]
           }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nitin Sahu for your reply. I am still getting the same download error.

Comment: What is the step are you following after download start.

Comment: I am validating that file is getting downloaded or not and logging out of application.

Comment: Try one more thing if file downloading takes 30 seconds manually then put 1 minute wait before logging out application. I doubt that it is failing because application gets log out before download completion.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think waiting is an issue because it was working 10 days ago. However I tried adding waiting time till 2 min but it is not working. I strongly believe that this is an issue with chrome driver or selenium webdriver version but I am not sure how to solve that either. Also notice from related online posts that 2-3 people are facing same issue but no solution.